# Can I remove a pending integration from an uncommitted revision?

Tags: perforce

I have an uncommitted changelist which contains a new file. I've integrated another file in (and I can see that operation in `p4 resolved`) but now I've changed my mind and want to remove the integration.

I could just revert the file and start over but it seems like there should be a better way. There could be other integrations that I want to preserve, for example.

Can I remove a specific pending integration without reverting the whole file?

Answer (score 0):

I am not sure there is a way, because it is seems the granularity of Perforce is at the file level.

Answer (score 0):

To preserve the content of your file, you could use

```
 p4 revert -k [file]
 p4 edit [file]
```

If necessary you could then integrate/merge and resolve with accept yours.